# VBA macro is taking too long to run

Tags: excel, vba

I have been running this code from months now and it takes 10 minutes on an average to run. Today, its been half an hour. 10 min also seem long though. Could anyone please guide what could be the issue? Am i using unnecessary lines?

```
Sub bench_extraction()

Dim countrows As Integer
Dim reqdcol As Integer
Dim skilllen As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim wscopy As Worksheet
Dim In_S As Worksheet

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Benchreport")

'Create copy of Bench report
sht.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

'Rename new bench report
ActiveSheet.Name = "Benchreport_Working"
Set wscopy = Sheets("Benchreport_Working")

Set StartCell = wscopy.Range("A1")
wscopy.Activate

LastRow = wscopy.Cells(wscopy.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = wscopy.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

'count number of max cells
countrows = LastRow - 1

'Find column no. in file
reqdcol = wscopy.Range("1:1").Find("Bench Type", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True).Column
reqdcol_1 = wscopy.Range("1:1").Find("Bench Ageing", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True).Column
reqdcol_2 = wscopy.Range("1:1").Find("Availability Status", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True).Column
reqdcol_3 = wscopy.Range("1:1").Find("User Payroll Location (current)", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True).Column
reqdcol_4 = wscopy.Range("1:1").Find("Detail Skill Set", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True).Column

Worksheets("Benchreport_working").UsedRange
wscopy.UsedRange.Select

'Apply filter on Partial Bench
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol, Criteria1:="Partial Bench"

'check if partial bench is found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Future Bench
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol, Criteria1:="Future Bench"

'Apply filter on days less than -30
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_1, Criteria1:="<" & -30
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_2, Criteria1:="<>" & "Confirm release"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Future Bench
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol, Criteria1:="Existing Bench-Future Allocation"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If


'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Availibility status
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_2, Criteria1:="Leave Exclusion"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Availibility status
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_2, Criteria1:="NTP Allocation"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Availibility status
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_2, Criteria1:="Resign"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Location
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_3, Criteria1:="=" & "*Germany"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Location
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_3, Criteria1:="=" & "NGR-DE-ANEGMBH"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Location
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_3, Criteria1:="=" & "*Romania"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Location
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_3, Criteria1:="=" & "*Austria"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Location
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_3, Criteria1:="=" & "*Norway"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

'Clear all filters
wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Apply filter on Location
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_4, Criteria1:=vbNullString

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If


wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter

check = 0

'Data is clean by now
'Duplicate the rows basis the skill set

For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1

        columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value

        'CHECK WHETHER TO KEEP THE COLUMN
        Select Case columnHeading
            Case "User Person Number", "User Name", "Detail Skill Set", "Bench Type", "Bench Ageing", "Active Blocker"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                  ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete

        End Select
    Next

LastRow = wscopy.Cells(wscopy.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = wscopy.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column

'count number of max cells
countrows = LastRow - 1

reqdcol_4 = wscopy.Range("1:1").Find("Detail Skill Set", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True).Column

check = 2

'Divide the colleagues basis number of skills
Do

    strl = wscopy.Cells(check, reqdcol_4)
    skilllen = Len(strl)
    strl = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(strl, ",", vbNullString)
    commacount = skilllen - Len(strl)

    If commacount <> 0 Then

    i = 0

        For i = 1 To commacount

            wscopy.Cells(check, reqdcol_4).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
            check = check + 1

        Next

    End If

LastRow = wscopy.Cells(wscopy.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
countrows = LastRow + 1
check = check + 1

Loop Until check = countrows

'Divide the skills

check = 2

Do

    strl = wscopy.Cells(check, reqdcol_4)
    skilllen = Len(strl)
    strl = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(strl, ",", vbNullString)
    commacount = skilllen - Len(strl)

    strl = wscopy.Cells(check, reqdcol_4).Value

    i = 0
    a = 1
    comm = 1

    If commacount <> 0 Then

        If commacount > 1 Then

        For i = 1 To commacount - 1

             If i = 1 Then
                comm = InStr(a, strl, ",", vbBinaryCompare)
                wscopy.Cells(check, reqdcol_4) = Mid(strl, 1, comm - 1)
             End If

             a = comm + 1
             comm = InStr(comm + 1, strl, ",", vbBinaryCompare)
             wscopy.Cells(check + 1, reqdcol_4) = Mid(strl, a, comm - a)

'             comm = InStr(comm + 1, strl, ",", vbBinaryCompare)
'             wscopy.Cells(i + 1, reqdcol_4) = Mid(strl, comm + 1, comm - (comm + 1))
             check = check + 1
        Next

            'comm = InStr(comm + 1, strl, ",", vbBinaryCompare)
            wscopy.Cells(check + 1, reqdcol_4) = Right(strl, Len(strl) - comm)
            check = Cells(check + 1, reqdcol_4).Row

        Else

            comm = InStr(a, strl, ",", vbBinaryCompare)
            wscopy.Cells(check, reqdcol_4) = Mid(strl, 1, comm - 1)
            a = comm + 1
            wscopy.Cells(check + 1, reqdcol_4) = Right(strl, Len(strl) - comm)
            check = Cells(check + 1, reqdcol_4).Row


        End If

    End If

LastRow = wscopy.Cells(wscopy.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
countrows = LastRow + 1
check = check + 1

Loop Until check = countrows

'Check for nan skill and remove it
check = 0

'Apply filter on Location
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=reqdcol_4, Criteria1:="nan"

'check if any rows are found
check = wscopy.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

If check > 0 Then

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wscopy.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

wscopy.Cells.AutoFilter


'Set dynamic range
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Bench_Data", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=OFFSET(Benchreport_Working!R1C1,0,0,COUNTA(Benchreport_Working!C1),COUNTA(Benchreport_Working!R1))"
ActiveWorkbook.Names("Bench_Data").Comment = ""

'Dim tbl As ListObject
'wscopy.UsedRange.Select
'Set tbl = wscopy.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)
'tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight8"
'tbl.Name = "Bench_ Data"

Set In_S = Sheets("Initial steps")
reqdcol_4 = wscopy.Range("1:1").Find("Detail Skill Set", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True).Column
wscopy.Columns(reqdcol_4).Copy
Sheets("Initial Steps").Activate
In_S.Range("L:L").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

LastColumn = wscopy.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
reqdcol_5 = wscopy.Range("1:1").Find("User Person Number", , xlValues, xlWhole, , , True).Column
wscopy.Columns(reqdcol_5).Copy
Sheets("Initial Steps").Activate
In_S.Range("N:N").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Range("N:N").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Please advice what can i do to make it run faster. What i am trying to do is clean the data basis some criteria and then through loop, diving a row into multiple rows basis the number of skills it has. Example, 1st row has 5 skills (Java, SQL, AngularJS, VBA, Python), then the loop will divide the row in 5 rows as 1st row: Java, 2nd row: SQL etc. This is where the code is taking the longest time.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can encourage other users to help you on your issue by providing a [minimal, reproducible and working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: For the first few tests you do, you apply multiple autofilters. These are costly operations. A better solution would be to loop over your database while testing each line against all of your values. Then add all line numbers that evaluate to true to a different array and delete all those at once. This might save you quite some time.

Comment: As for your loop splitting a row into multiple, inserting rows is more costly than pasting them at the end. You could opt to add all newly created rows on at the end, and then filter your database, rather than insert the rows.

Comment: Thank you Plutian. Will try that. As for inserting them at the end, do i make the macro go down after every row? wont that be time consuming too?

Comment: Thank you jhoepken. I tried giving an example of how code works. Should i attach sample excel here for better understanding?

Comment: @user12467092 you don't have to make the "Macro go down" after every row. What you do is replace this `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow` with `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0)` This will paste it to the end of your data, rather than insert a new row right below. Pushing all your data down when inserting is quite a slow operation.

Comment: Thank you Plutian. Unfortunately, it is still taking a lot of time. Deleting basis various criteria is taking around 4 secs, i checked by step through; however, the rest of the macro is still taking a lot of time (10 minutes already and counting) any more suggestions?

Comment: Hi, Can anybody please help??